# FOSUserBundle : override form

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to override FOSUserBundle form "Edit profile" ; I have created the class `EditFormType` under `AP/UserBundle/Form/Type` as :

```
<?php
namespace FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType as BaseType;

class EditFormType extends BaseType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $child = $builder->create('user', 'form', array('data_class' => $this->class));
        $this->buildUserForm($child, $options);

        $builder
            ->add($child)
            ->add('Mot de passe', 'password')
            ->add('Nom', 'nom')
            ->add('Prénom', 'prenom')
            ->add('Civilité', 'civilite')
            ->add('Newsletter', 'new_letter')
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Model\CheckPassword');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ap_edit_profile';
    }
}
```

Then, I've created my services `AP/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` :

```
services:
    ap_user.edit.form.type:
        class: AP\UserBundle\Form\Type\EditFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: ap_edit_profile }
```

And lastly, I updated `app/config/config.yml` :

```
fos_user:
    profile:
        form:
        type: ap_edit_profile
```

And I've finally got this error : `Could not load type "ap_edit_profile"`

What can be wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try to request the type directly by creating a dummy controller and requesting var_dump($this->container->get('ap_edit_profile')); See what errors will come up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose problem in this part of configuration

```
fos_user:
    profile:
        form:
        type: ap_edit_profile
```

it should look like

```
fos_user:
    profile:
        form:
            type: ap_edit_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

First try what I wrote in the comment, which will probably fail with something like `could not find bla bla`, then replace this line:

> namespace FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type;

with this:

> namespace AP/UserBundle/Form/Type;

Also make sure your bundle extends FOS one:

> ```
> public function getParent()
> {
>     return 'FOSUserBundle';
> }
> ```

in your main *Bundle.php file

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to override the `buildUserForm()` function instead of `buildForm()`.
Then you can add all the items you want to the form builder (just don't forget to call `parent::buildUserForm($builder, $options)` beforehand (from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830233/fosuserbundle-and-symfony-2-template-and-edits)).