# FosUserbundle and symfony 2 template and edits

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am new to symfony 2. I have just setup with basic FOSuserbundle. But I have a few problems:

1. I have setup the new layout template but I could not find where to change the form template for login, registration, profile
2. I could not find how to edit the user profile. I can view the profile using /profile but I could not find any edit link there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers on your questions you can find inside [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/doc). Here are some points:

1. Copy templates you want to modify from `FOSUserBundle/Resources/views` into your bundle and do changes you want.
2. If you need to make a custom profile form (as I guess based on your question), then you have to create profile form type and specify that FOSUserBundle uses it.

#### config.yml

```
services:
  my_user.profile.form.type:
    class: My\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
    arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: my_user_profile }

fos_user:
  profile:
    form:
      type: my_user_profile
```

#### ProfileFormType.php

```
<?php

namespace My\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType as BaseType;

class ProfileFormType extends BaseType
{

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_user_profile';
    }

    protected function buildUserForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but i even can't find routing URL for default profile edit.

Comment: It is inside `vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml`

Answer (score 2):

@Anton has the correct answer for the first part of your question but to answer the second part, if you can view your profile from `/profile` you can edit by going to `/profile/edit` in your browser.

There is no edit link on the default profile form. If you want one, you'll need to take the advice of @Anton and copy the default form template(s) and paste them into a directory with the same name in your bundle.

As @Anton already pointed out, all of the details on how to do this are in either the [master documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) or the [documentation for version 1.2.0](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.0/Resources/doc/index.md) (which you will need if you are using Symfony 2.0.*